# Rails compute view by helper - Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view, which calls a method from a Helper, which actually builds the view with methods like contant_tag, link_to and then returns it as html_safe. However I wonder if this needs more time performance than actually describing the view as plain html in the html.erb file. This is because it really takes its time to display the view. I also use a gem and do many requests to another web service. So I always thought that the requests make the time difference.

But before I start to build the html.erb file to replace the helper method I wanted to know, if this is really an advantage regarding time performance.

Thanks for any advices.

Best regards

Comment: Similar to [In rails, whether to use form helpers or not to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430997/in-rails-whether-to-use-form-helpers-or-not-to)

Comment: Not quite. Take a look at the following example:

`def safe_html_for_spreadsheets(spreadsheets, email)
    contents = ''

    for entry in spreadsheets
      li_tag = content_tag(:li) {
        check_box_tag('entries[]', entry.key).html_safe +
        (entry.title + ' ').html_safe +
        link_to('View', entry.human_url, :target => '_blank').html_safe 
      }

      contents << li_tag
    end

    contents.html_safe
end`

This gets called a lot. And I wonder if this would be faster, when using direct HTML in the view instead of creating it in the rails helper.